# how to increment interger array by 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an **array** like so [1,9,9,9,9,9]. I want to increment this array by one and return [2,0,0,0,0,0]. Here's the catch - you can't join() or concat().  You cannot change the array in any way other than adding to it.  However, you can reverse it but I'm not sure how much that would help

**Also, here are a few other examples;**

[1,8,9] => [1,9,0];

[1,2,3,9,1] => [1,2,3,9,2];

[5,7,9,9] => [5,8,0,0];

The result can only return an array with single digits.

Basically, pretend that the array is a single number and you're adding 1 to it. Again, no joining, splitting, turning into a string.. etc.

Ideally, I would like a classic loop solution or possibly a recursion solution. Thank you!

here is my repl.it   https://repl.it/@CharChar5/Code-Challenge

Thank you in advance for your help and I'm terribly sorry  if my questions title is too long and confusing.  I'm certainly working on formatting better questions and building a stronger rep on SO.

https://repl.it/@CharChar5/Code-Challenge

Currently this is my code:

```
    jjChallenge=(j)=>{
     const len = j.length;
     const newArray = [];
      for(var i = 0; i<j.length; i++){
        if (j[i] == 9) {

         if(j[i-1] == 9) {

           n = 0;

        } else {

          newArray[i-1] = newArray[i-1] + 1;
          n = 0;
        }
         newArray.push(n);
         } else {
      newArray.push(j[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(newArray)
}


   jjChallenge([2,9,9,9]) //works and returns [3,0,0,0]
    //[2,9,8,9] doesnt work and returns [3,0,9,0]
```

Comment: My apologies for the horrendous title.  Please post a few alternate options if you can think of any.

Comment: Please put code in your question instead of on an external site.

Comment: `Without Join(),concat() or making it a string`, I can smell the school homework ten miles away

Comment: Lol.  Nah buddy.  I was presented with this challenge at an interview and it stumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse it and increment with carry and then reverse it back

Something like
eg

```js
function incrementIntArray(arr) {
  var reverseArray = arr.reverse();
  var newReverseArray = [];
  var carry = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var curNum = reverseArray[i];
    if (i == 0 || carry) curNum++;
    if (curNum > 9) {
      carry = true;
      curNum = 0;
    } else {
      carry = false;
    }
    newReverseArray[i] = curNum;
  }
  return newReverseArray.reverse();
}

var arr1 = [1, 8, 9];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 9, 1];
var arr3 = [5, 7, 9, 9];
console.log(incrementIntArray(arr1)); //outputs [1,9,0]
console.log(incrementIntArray(arr2)); //outputs [1,2,3,9,2]
console.log(incrementIntArray(arr3)); //outputs [5,8,0,0]
```

Your code was trying to carry, but it's difficult to carry when coming from the top down, hence the reverse and then its easier to carry from bottom up

Comment: You sir are the man!  That works perfectly!  Thank you! Problem solved. Any thoughts on a title change?  Not sure why someone downvoted me.. it was just a question.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Added slight code tidy up inside function with all you user cases tests.... as far as title, perhaps _how to increment interger array by 1_ PS you gave the answer away when you said you can use reverse too BTW

Comment: People downvote here if questions are just 'give me some code' kinda of question. your question should have lead with the code you had tried and why it wasn't working.... and besides looks like this is a homework kinda question, isn;t the point of these kinda questions for you to learn... not someone else do it for you...... Best make sure questions are on topic for SO see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yeah  - totally get it.  Not homework.  I got this question in an interview and it stumped me.  So was looking for a little guidance.  I did post my code through repl.it link and included which part works and which part doesn't.  If i knew why it wasn't working i probably wouldn't have posted the question...

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
jjChallenge=(arr)=>{
  newArray=arr.map((element) => {
    return element==9?0:element+1
  })
  return newArray
}


jjChallenge([2,9,9,9])
```

Comment: your code returns this [ 3, 10, 10, 10 ] but was looking for this
=> [3,0,0,0 ].  Thank you for your response tho

Comment: oh. i have edited my answer to fulfill your additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Just sum the digits up and then plus one. After that, split it.

Simple and Clean that complies with

> you can't join() or concat(). You cannot change the array in any way other than adding to it.

```js
addOne = (data) => {
  let sum = 0, digit = data.length - 1
  data.forEach(n => sum += n * (10 ** digit--))
  return (sum + 1).toString().split("")
}
console.log(addOne([1,8,9]))
console.log(addOne([1,2,3,9,1]))
console.log(addOne([5,7,9,9]))
```